# build demo version .exe

Tags: python, build, exe, pyinstaller, demo

the time has come and i start think about how to build demo version of my software to show it to my clints. i make buildings via pyinstaller. i need to create programm that will be stop working after 1 or 2 days of using.

it should be easy i hope ?) i cant find any information about this buildings via pyinstaller

```
pyinstaller --onefile script.py
```

may be i need use other builder like pyfreeze ? or maybe i can do that in python logic level or setup setup file in builder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be done manually by hardcoding a timelimit at the top of `script.py`, using the `time` module.

```
import time
limit_str = 'Wed Feb 26 12:30:00 2014'
limit = time.mktime(time.strptime(limit_str))

if time.time() > limit:
    print 'Demo time expired!'
else:
    print 'Program logic here'
```

Comment: hmm. this solution can be solved by changing time in operation system.. do you know way to make it more secure may be?

Comment: may be get real world time from web?

Comment: Hah, I suppose that's true! Getting the time from somewhere online sounds as good a solution as any.